# C++: Sieve Of Eratosthenes Not Always Working

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am making a C++ program to find prime numbers using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Currently I have the following code:

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class is_multiple_of {
    int m_div;
public:
    is_multiple_of(int div) : m_div(div) {}
    bool operator()(int n) { return ((n > m_div) && (0 == n % m_div)); }
};

int main ()
{
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i=2; i<=100; i++) v.push_back(i);

    v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_multiple_of(2)), v.end() );
    v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_multiple_of(3)), v.end() ); 
    v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_multiple_of(5)), v.end() ); 
    v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_multiple_of(7)), v.end() ); 

    for (unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        cout << v[i] << " ";


    cout << endl << v.size();
    return 0;
}
```

which works fine i.e. it says there are 25 primes between 1 and 100 (which is [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how%20many%20prime%20numbers%20are%20between%201%20and%20100)). However, if i want to know the first 500 primes for example, it will say there are 118 where in reality there are 95. To correct this issue, I have to add more multiples to remove i.e. `v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_multiple_of(11)), v.end() );` and then add more `is_multiple_of()`'s.

Is there a way to make this more efficient rather than just having it remove more multiples of previously found primes?

Comment: How is your code implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes (as described in the wiki link) ?

Comment: It removes all multiples of 2 (evens), then all multiples of 3, followed by 5, then 7, then 11 (you see where this is going)

Comment: @Bijan where do you remove multiples of 11?

Comment: I get what your code does, but it is not implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Comment: @FDinoff: I don't but my point is that it removes multiples of all prime numbers.

Comment: Why don't you use standard sieve implementation(like in wikipedia)? It is correct and more efficient.

Comment: For the Sieve to work you have to remove all primes up to `sqrt(n)`. For `n==100` this is 10 but for `n==500` this is 19.

Comment: Use a loop instead of repeating `v.erase` a bunch of times. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7ba1551593c316

Comment: I think you need a boolean function instead of a class for `is_multiple_of`.

Comment: @Logicrat, `is_multiple_of` satisfies the `UnaryPredicate` concept, so it's correct.

Comment: @Bijan When you say "more efficient", do you mean efficient in terms of not having to write so many `v_erase` lines, or efficient in terms of execution time?

Comment: "More efficient" is kinda meaningless when the original implementation is broken...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I mean efficient as in not having to continually write v.erase(). I guess my implementation of Sieve of eratosthenes is wrong but i would still like to complete it using my method of v.erase

Comment: @Bijan In that case, check out my example above. You should loop through the contents of `v`, `erase`ing as you go until `*it * *it` (i.e. `n^2`) is `> N`. Here's the same, timed with `N = 10 million`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3f9fdc1433d6737

Comment: @tclamb Upon closer inspection I see that you are indeed correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to implement your version of finding the primes, then the following should work (we are using 500)

```
 int stopInt = static_cast<int>(sqrt(500));
 int j = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < stopInt; ++i, ++j)
     v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_multiple_of(v[j])), v.end());
```

Here is an alternative that "marks" the items by just moving them to the end of the vector:

```
     vector<int>::iterator sMarked = v.end();
     int stopInt = static_cast<int>(sqrt(500));
     int j = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < stopInt; ++i, ++j)
         sMarked = remove_if(v.begin(), sMarked, is_multiple_of(v[j]));
     v.erase(sMarked, v.end());
```

So we're constantly marking the elements by keeping track of the return value of `remove_if`.  Then at the end, we do one single `vector::erase` to remove the multiples.  This should be more efficient than calling the `v_erase` constantly in the loop.